# aura:doneRendering not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I prototyped a  component based on this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_doneRendering.htm). It will call a function when doneRendering is occured.

But when I doing this it is not calling the function assigned to it. I want to know why it is not working or is there something missing?

Below is my code.

**Component**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="String" access="public" />
    <aura:handler event="aura:doneRendering" action="{!c.done}" />
    <div>
        {!v.value}
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
({
    done : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('done rendering'); //Not executed.
    }
})
```

Code for the **Parent Application**

```
<aura:application >
    <c:Dummy_test value="test" />
</aura:application>
```

**PS: I checked with both locker service enabled and disabled.**

**Update**

After researching on this I observed that If there is any ui input tags like `ui:inputText`, `ui:inputNumber` in the component it is firing the doneRendering event.

**Component**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="String" access="public" />
    <aura:handler event="aura:doneRendering" action="{!c.done}" />
    <div>
        {!v.value}
    </div>
    <ui:inputText />
</aura:component>
```

I used with some other tags like `ui:button`, `ui:outputText`. But it doesn't work.

Is this the way the `aura:doneRendering` works? or Is this a **bug** in aura framework?

Comment: Where is that component used? Maybe the problem is in the app or parent component that makes the child component not rendering, can you share that code too?

Comment: Seems like this is broken ! Raise a case with support !

Comment: I've added the code for the parent component @D.Cruz .

Comment: It's very strange why your component is not triggering the render function. But for your case you can try the workaround of using init instead of doneRendering: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_init_handler.htm.